# Is it possible to migrate bootable VHDX content to an UEFI booted HDD

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, uefi, vhdx

I have a VHDX file with bootable Windows 10 system which was used as a 2nd dual-boot system on another Windows 10 instance (natively VHDX booted). Now I want to make the content of this VHDX file to my primary content on the Disk and boot from it direcly on a computer which is UEFI only.

I did following:

1. mounted VHDX in running windows 10 as virtual disk
2. used HDD copy Raw tool to clone the content of the VHDX to a free HDD (both partitions - recovery 600MB and the standard system partitions, partition is active, should be bootable)
3. made the HDD to a primary disk in the computer (physically swapped the disks)
4. boot does not work (I assume because it is not UEFI)
5. mbr2gpt /validate /disk:0 /allowsFullOS -> shows everything is ok with the disk
6. mbr2gpt /convert /disk:0 /allowsFullOS -> shows error Cannot find room for the EFI system partition
7. used a partitionwizard tool to make between the recovery and the system partition extra 110MB space
8. mbr2gpt /convert /disk:0 /allowsFullOS -> shows error Cannot find OS partition(s) for Disk 0
9. mbr2gpt /validate / disk:0 /allowsFullOS -> shows error Cannot find OS partition(s) for Disk 0
10. tried to boot Windows 10 installation, and from Shilft + F10 console the mbr2gpt command, again, same error

my conclusion is that the partitionwizard tool managed to 'move' the 2nd partition to make there an extra space for the EFI partition but somehow it went wrong or maybe such migration is not possible in theory at all..

is there some another magic (free) tool which could do this job? EasyUS seems not to be free any more and I am not sure it could do this job either if I would pay for it.

many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that kind of works: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2117288-switch-vm-from-bios-to-uefi-boot

It is based on the idea to raw-copy the mounted vhdx drive into a physical disk and than using diskpart to remove the boot and reserved system partitions and recreate them in the new GPT EFI format.

Using the steps from the link I managed to create a bootable system but when I tried to enable BitLocker I received an error. The partitions created by the steps are not exactly identical to the ones that are created by fresh Win10 installation which is a problem for BitLocker.

In the end I installed windows from scratch with EFI configuration...